# ParserError: Expected '{' but got '(' function stake() public payable ()

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.7.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "./ExampleExternalContract.sol";

contract Staker {
    
    ExampleExternalContract public exampleExternalContract;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;
    uint256 public constant treshold = 1 ether;
    event Stake(address staker, uint256 amount);
    
    constructor(address exampleExternalContractAddress) public {
        exampleExternalContract = ExampleExternalContract(exampleExternalContractAddress);
    }
    
    function stake() public payable () {
        balances[msg.sender] = msg.value;
        emit Stake(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
}
```

I am getting a parse error Expected '{' but got '(', when I try to deploy this code. Any thoughts on what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra pair of parentheses in the `stake` function definition.

Replace this

```
function stake() public payable () {
```

with this

```
function stake() public payable {
```